# Trying to get property 'object' of non-object in my laravel project

Tags: json, laravel, api

I'm new to laravel and created a mini project using RestAPI and Laravel.

Here's my controller

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Market;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
Use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;    
public function index()
    {
        $responses = Http::withHeaders([
                    'x-rapidapi-key' => 'ec7c376536msh7ef70636f1cb7a2p194fafjsnc913c1436f23',
                    'x-rapidapi-host' => 'apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com',
                    "useQueryString" => true
        ])
                    ->get('https://apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com/market/get-summary', [
                        'region' => "ID",
                    ])
                    ->json();
                    // dd($responses);
        return view ('market.index', compact('responses'));
```

it was successfully when im trying dd, but when im try to open my index blade and and using blade templates it error

this my json

```
array:1 [▼
  "marketSummaryResponse" => array:2 [▼
    "result" => array:15 [▼
      0 => array:24 [▼
        "exchangeTimezoneName" => "America/New_York"
        "fullExchangeName" => "SNP"
        "symbol" => "^GSPC"
        "regularMarketChange" => array:2 [▶]
        "gmtOffSetMilliseconds" => -18000000
        "exchangeDataDelayedBy" => 0
        "firstTradeDateMilliseconds" => -1325583000000
        "language" => "en-US"
        "regularMarketTime" => array:2 [▶]
        "regularMarketChangePercent" => array:2 [▶]
        "exchangeTimezoneShortName" => "EST"
        "quoteType" => "INDEX"
        "regularMarketPrice" => array:2 [▶]
        "marketState" => "REGULAR"
        "market" => "us_market"
        "quoteSourceName" => "Free Realtime Quote"
        "priceHint" => 2
        "tradeable" => false
        "sourceInterval" => 15
        "exchange" => "SNP"
        "shortName" => "S&P 500"
        "region" => "US"
        "regularMarketPreviousClose" => array:2 [▶]
        "triggerable" => false
      ]
      1 => array:24 [▶]
      2 => array:24 [▶]
      3 => array:23 [▶]
      4 => array:25 [▶]
      5 => array:25 [▶]
      6 => array:25 [▶]
      7 => array:25 [▶]
      8 => array:24 [▶]
      9 => array:25 [▶]
      10 => array:25 [▶]
      11 => array:22 [▶]
      12 => array:24 [▶]
      13 => array:23 [▶]
      14 => array:23 [▶]
    ]
    "error" => null
  ]
]
```

here my index blade

```
@extends('layout/main')

@section('title', 'Fundamental')

@section('container')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-10">
                <h1>Analysis Fundamental</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    <div>
        <li>
    @foreach($responses as $response)
        
            {{ $response->result }}

        </li>
    @endforeach
    </div>



    </div>
@endsection
```

please help me it was taking my time so long :v

sorry for my bad english

Comment: You have arrays, not objects. You likely need to use `$response['result']` instead of `$response->result`.

Comment: Not to mention `$response['result']` is an array itself, you can't output it as a string like that.

Comment: after that i got a new problem to be "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\fundamental\resources\views\market\index.blade.php)"